# What does it mean to evaluate in c++?

Tags: c++

I cannot understand what it means to evaluate something in c++. I have this sentence: " Its syntax is:

condition ? result1 : result2

If condition is true, the entire expression evaluates to result1, and otherwise to result2." I know what the point is but I can't really get the meaning of the word "evaluate" straight in this context. Does it mean something like to continue, to check or what?
Thanks! Much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Every expression has a value. That value is obtained by *evaluating* the expression. And in some forced contortion of the English language, we sometimes say that "the expression evaluates to [something]".

The evaluation of expressions generally happens at runtime, it is a runtime property of your program. (The exception are constant expressions.)

The rules for evaluation are defined recursive:

- A literal evaluates to the value it represents, e.g. `5` evaluates to the value "5".
- An expression `a + b` evaluates to the mathematical sum of the values of the expressions `a` and `b`. (So to evaluate the expression `a + b`, you first have to evaluate the expressions `a` and `b`.)
- The expression `a = b` evaluates to the new value of `a` (and has a *side effect*, which is to change the value of the lvalue designated by `a` to the value of `b`).
- ... and so on ...
- The expression `c ? a : b` evaluates to the conversion of either `a` or `b`, depending on the value of `c`, to the common type of the types of `a` and `b`.

Note that not all expressions are evaluated. For example, in the expression `sizeof(+a)`, neither the subexpression `+a` nor the subexpression `a` are evaluated. Similarly, in the conditional expression the unused expression is not evaluated, and in logical expressions, the short-circuited dead expression is not evaluated.

"Undefined behaviour at runtime" is usually a consequence of expression evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

It is shorthand syntax of `if else`. If the condition of the expression (condition) is true `result1` will be executed else `result2`. 
It is the short form of if else, Like.

```
if(condition){
   result1;
}else{
   result2;
}
```

Practical example.

```
int age = 25;
age >= 25 ? cout << "Result 1" : cout << "result 2";
```

**Explanation:** If age is greater than or equal to 25, Result 1 else Result 2.
`Evaluate` means that if you get true from the `condition`(expression) result1 and if you get false result2.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operator evaluates an expression, returning one value if that expression evaluates to true, and a different one if the expression evaluates as false. Its syntax is:

```
condition ? result1 : result2
```

If condition is true, the entire expression evaluates to result1, and otherwise to result2.

```
7==5 ? 4 : 3     // evaluates to 3, since 7 is not equal to 5.
7==5+2 ? 4 : 3   // evaluates to 4, since 7 is equal to 5+2.
5>3 ? a : b      // evaluates to the value of a, since 5 is greater than 3.
a>b ? a : b      // evaluates to whichever is greater, a or b.
```

> I can't really get the meaning of the word "evaluate" straight in
>   this context

it means that the expression has a single value after evaluation . for example in this

```
7==5 ? 4 : 3     // evaluates to 3, since 7 is not equal to 5.
```

the expression evaluates to 3 (i.e the value of expression is 3)
before evaluation it could have been 4 or 3 but after evaluation the expression equals to 3

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, we'll take a complete statement, as the one you have posted is incomplete:

```
store = condition ? result1 : result2
```

> *If condition is true, the entire expression evaluates to `result1`, and otherwise to `result2`*

This means that if the expression, which is called `condition` in your shortened if-statement, is true, then `result1` is stored in the variable on the left-hand side of the equation, which is `store` here.

On the other hand, if `condition`is not true, then `result2` will be stored in `store`. That's all what the expression means.

This kind of expression is a shortened if-else statement. If you were to convert this statement into a full if-else statement, then it would look something like:

```
if (condition == true)
    store = result1;

else 
    store = result2;
```

Here is an example of this kind of statement:

Suppose we have:

```
int num = 5;

int var = (num == 5) ? 6 : 10;
```

Then we can expand this statement to be rewritten **with the same meaning** as follows:

```
int num = 5;
int var;

if (num == 5)
    var = 6;

else
    var = 10;
```

In both cases here, the resulting expression results in *6* being stored in `var`.

---

So in short, ***evaluates*** simply means that the resulting expression based on the if-else comparison is evaluated, and the resulting value is passed to the variable on the left. Sometimes, there may not be a variable on the left side, and in that case, the function or expression being "evaluated" will be run. An example like:

```
(num == 5) ? cout << "result1" : cout << "result2";
```

Will output *result1* in the end.

Also, an example like:

```
(num == 5) ? cout << 5 + 23 : cout << 4 + 32;
```

Will ***evaluate*** the first expression (since `num`is initialized to 5 from the previous example) to 28, and then output that.

Hope this helps.